# Use CASE statements with PARTITION in sql

Tags: sql, case, partitioning, where-in

Given the following `table_a`:

```
 id  | status | reg_date | so_date
 ----+------------------------------
  1  |   abc  | 15-11-01 | 15-11-02 
  1  |   def  | 15-11-01 | 15-11-04
  1  |   abc  | 15-11-01 | 15-11-06
  2  |   abc  | 15-11-01 | 15-11-03
  2  |   abc  | 15-11-01 | 15-11-04
  2  |   abc  | 15-11-01 | 15-11-06
  2  |   abc  | 15-11-01 | 15-11-08
  3  |   xyz  | 15-11-01 | 15-11-03
  3  |   def  | 15-11-01 | 15-11-08
  3  |   def  | 15-11-01 | 15-11-09
```

The following is required:
For every group of `id`, the minimum difference between `so_date` and `reg_date`, if the `status` is "abc". This yields the following table:

```
 id  | min_date  
 ----+----------
  1  |    1   
  2  |    2   
  3  |   Null
```

The following code would suffice:

```
select 
    id,
    distinct datediff('day', reg_date, min(so_date) over (partition by id)) as min_date
from table_a  
where status ilike '%abc%'
```

However, due to constraints of other "selections", the use of the filter `where status ilike '%abc%'` is not feasible at the base table. I tried using

```
 select 
        id,
        case when status is like '%abc%' then (distinct datediff('day', reg_date, min(so_date) over (partition by id))) end as min_date
    from table_a
```

But this did not work. Any insights/suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Based on your sample should be

```
select 
    id
  , min (datediff( so_date, reg_date )) as min_date
from table_a 
where status ='abc'
group by id
```

if you don't want where bat case then

```
select 
   case status when 'abc' then  id end
  , case status when 'abc' then min (datediff( so_date, reg_date ))  end as min_date
from table_a 
group by id
```

Comment: Thanks. However, as requested in the question, is there a way to code this without using the `where status = 'abc'`  filter in the base table?

Comment: how you want filter the rows for abc?why you don't want =

Comment: Anyway i have update the answer with case (Avoding where)